# console.log returns "Object" for some fields, instead of body data [spotify-web-api-node]

Tags: node.js, json, spotify, console.log

I'm using the [spotify-web-api-node](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node) and when I do api calls, the returned data looks like that in the console:

```
Album information {
  album_type: 'album',
  artists: [
    {
      external_urls: [Object],
      href: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/2hazSY4Ef3aB9ATXW7F5w3',   
      id: '2hazSY4Ef3aB9ATXW7F5w3',
      name: 'IZAL',
      type: 'artist',
      uri: 'spotify:artist:2hazSY4Ef3aB9ATXW7F5w3'
    }
  ],

  ...

  label: 'Hook Ediciones Musicales',
  name: 'Agujeros de Gusano',
  popularity: 0,
  release_date: '2014-01-25',
  release_date_precision: 'day',
  total_tracks: 13,
  tracks: {
offset=0&limit=50',
    items: [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object]
    ],
    limit: 50,
    next: null,
    offset: 0,
    previous: null,
    total: 13
  },
  type: 'album',
  uri: 'spotify:album:5U4W9E5WsYb2jUQWePT8Xm'
}
```

As you can see, some fields like `external_urls:` and (later) `items:` have `[Object]` returned, instead of the actual data.
The (node.js) code for that particular example is the following:

```
spotifyApi.getAlbum('5U4W9E5WsYb2jUQWePT8Xm')
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log('Album information',data.body);
  }, function(err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

If I change the `data.body` part in `console.log` to `JSON.stringify(data.body)` it is somewhat better, as it does return the data, but as a string (obviously), which not exactly... useable:

```
Album information {"album_type":"album","artists":[{"external_urls":{"spotify":"https://open.spotify.com/artist/2hazSY4Ef3aB9ATXW7F5w3"},"href":"https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/2hazSY4Ef3aB9ATXW7F5w3","id":"2hazSY4Ef3aB9ATXW7F5w3","name":"IZAL","type":"artist","uri":"spotify:artist:2hazSY4Ef3aB9ATXW7F5w3"}],"available_markets":[],"copyrights":[{"text":"2013 Hook Ediciones Musicales","type":"C"},{"text":"2013 Hook Ediciones Musicales","type":"P"}],
```

etc etc. Also tried `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.body))` but I get the same output as with `console.log`.

How can I get the field's actual data, without losing its format?

Comment: You may want to use `util.inspect` with its `depth` parameter. https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options

Comment: @snak Thanks! I changed the line to: console.log('Album information',util.inspect(data.body, false, null, true));
, and it seems to work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @snak 's comment, I changed the `console.log` line to:

`console.log('Album information',util.inspect(data.body, false, null, true));`

and it seems to return everything fine, no `[Object]`.

(Make sure to include `const util = require('util');` and install it with `npm install util --save`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `console.log(JSON.stringify(data.body, null, 2))`.

That prints JSON in tree without losing its content like you see in [Object].

Comment: Still returns them as [Object]